# Function that allows only certain amount of digits as integer in decimal and also a certain amount of decimal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I was wondering if you guys can help me out on building a function in Javascript that is executed in the keypress event that prevents to have more than 10 digits as Integer and 2 as decimals.

```
Correct format: 1234567890.12 (10 digits as integer and 2 decimal)
Wrong format: 123456778901.123 (11 digits as integer and 3 decimal)
```

In case the user enters more than 10 digits as integer, it should return false to not add it but to leave the 2 decimal points if defined already.

I would do it myself but I ran out of ideas :(

This is what I was trying but it never let me to respect the 2 decimal points.

```
const theIntegerNumber = ($scope[ngModelName] - ($scope[ngModelName] % 1).toFixed(2)).toFixed(0);

if( theIntegerNumber.length >= 10){
    $scope[ngModelName] = parseFloat($scope[ngModelName]).toFixed(2);
    $event.preventDefault();
}
// I am using angular tho.
```

**Edit:**

`<input ng-model="__incomeUnitAmount" ng-keypress="filterValueAcceptedData('__incomeUnitAmount', '__incomeUnitAmount_error_format', '10Digit2Decimal', $event);"  type="text" name="incomeUnitAmount-amount"`>

Comment: *"in the keypress event*" - Might want to use the `input` event, so that your validation works on mouse and *Edit* menu based editing.

Comment: It actually does it on the input keypress event.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

```js
var regex = new RegExp("^\\d{0,10}\.\\d{2}$");

isValidFormat = function(str) {
  return regex.test(str);
}

console.log('%s: %s', '1234567890.10', isValidFormat("1234567890.10"));
console.log('%s: %s', '123456778901.123', isValidFormat("123456778901.123"));
```

**Edit:**

The pattern has been updated to make the dot and the fractional part of number optionals (because dot and decimals are generally not immediately entered by the user).

With Angular, using the `ng-pattern` directive:

```js
function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="intValue" name="int_field" ng-pattern="/^\d{1,10}\.?\d{0,2}$/" required><br/>
    <span ng-show="myForm.int_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span><br/>
   <tt>myForm.price_field.$error.pattern = {{myForm.int_field.$error.pattern}}</tt><br/>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Kenavoz, this piece of code looks like its the path to follow but, in my case, when user starts entering the data, I don't know why it is returning false when I enter the first two digits, after that it becomes true but doesn't return false when reached the 10 digit Integer. :(

Comment: The event occurs when the user presses the key, if more than 10 digits reached, it should return the "preventDefault()" and not add the 11th digit to the field. I have edited my question adding the HTML field where it shows that I am returning a function when that event occurs which validates the field. So, showing the error is not enough, I think the path then is the regex, but it's still returning false the first two digits and the rest is true, when "." entered, becomes true, then first decimal false, second decimal true. What do you think it could be going wrong? Thanks a lot for your time